# Finding document root based on virtual alias?

Tags: regex, apache

Can I find the document root of something based on this snippet of virtual alias i have that is in a /etc/httpd/sites-enabled folder?

```
#
# Apogee LN2
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName whatiwant.example.com

    ServerAlias whatiwant
#   DocumentRoot /rproxy/nowhere

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass       /   http://whatiwant-1.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://whatiwant-1.example.com/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from \
            10. 192.55.555. \
            .pvtn.net .pvtnetworks.net .doit.edu .something.net \
            others
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Trying to find out where the code for whatiwant lives, sad to see the DocumentRoot below is commented so that is a meaningless line.  Where else can I see where this code is?   Or how to find where on disk the whatiwant.example.com is pointing when all I really have is the URL to go off of?

Comment: Check which conf file included this conf file. It seems there is one default `DocumentRoot` for all virtual hosts.

Comment: I don't see which one includes this, i see in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf where it does have a document root, though nothing in that website above is in that root.  Furthermore unless I am approaching this wrong.  I went in as root to / and did a `find . -name states.gif` which is a file on that website whatiwant.exmaple.com that is loaded from the notes.html of that website.  It cannot find that file (or notes.html) unless my linux fu is bad and I am searching wrong? if I ping the url above though it shows it as my webserver?!

Comment: Do `find . -type f | xargs grep -in documentroot` in `/etc/httpd/` directory to see all document roots (either commented out or not)

Comment: I see a ton of `/rproxy/nowhere` which are commented out.  I have no idea what it is (if it isnt clear, inherited this webserver and all the apps onsite with no documentation) so trying to figure out where things live, someone asked for an update on this app at the url so now I gotta find where it lives to do the update!